# value comes out as zero for rectangle class

Tags: objective-c

1. When I compile this I keep getting zeros instead of the values any suggestions?
2. The code here is about a simple rectangle class I created.

   ```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface Rectangle : NSObject {
          int width;
          int height;
    }
    @property int width, height;
    -(int) area;
    -(int) perimeter;
    -(void) setWH: (int) h: (int) w;

    @end


    #import "Rectangle.h"

    @implementation Rectangle
    @synthesize width, height;
    -(int) area {
         width*height;
    }
    -(int) perimeter {
         (width+height)*2;
    }
    -(void) setWH:(int)h :(int)w {
          w = width;
          h = height;
    }
    @end



    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Rectangle.h" 

    int main (int argc, const char*argv[]) {
           @autoreleasepool {
                  Rectangle* r = [[Rectangle alloc]init];

                  [r setWH: 6:8];
                  NSLog(@"the width of the rectangle is %i and the hieght %i", r.width, r.height);
                  NSLog(@"the area is %i and the perimeter is %i", [r perimeter], [r area]);

      }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

you flipped the variable assignment:

```
-(void) setWH:(int)h :(int)w {
       w = width;
       h = height;
 }
```

it should be

```
-(void) setWH:(int)h :(int)w {
       width = w;
       height = h;
 }
```

Comment: And it really should be `setWH:(int)w :(int)h`, so that the name order corresponds to the parameter order.

Comment: or better `-(void) setWidth:(int)w andHeight:(int)h` clearer than setWH.

Comment: @PerfectPixel - Yeah, though the original isn't that bad of a way to do it, with the parms in the right order.  A little less cluttered, especially if you'll be using the method a lot.

Comment: @HotLicks sure, I just fear the day of `int no1337 = 1`. I like to know what everything does without having to look it up. But that is just my personal preference. :-)

Comment: the problem is when i compile it now i get the width and height right but the area and perimeter come out with errors and as zeros when compiled

Comment: you have to `return` your values. e.g. `return width*height;`

Comment: @user2304873 - Wasn't the compiler giving you all sorts of warnings about missing a return statement??

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning I didn't understand how it even compiles, since you can't access a property without `self`. Then I saw instance variables.

```
 @interface Rectangle : NSObject {
       int width;
       int height;
 }
 @property int width, height;
```

Don't do that.
In modern objective-c you don't have to write instance variables for properties at all, they will be automatically synthesized (by the way you don't need `@synthesize` either). You are free to write them, of course (especially if you're starting to learn OBjective-C) but then you'd better pick other names for instance variables, because otherwise it causes confusion.
A standard practice is to prepend a property name with an underscore.

```
//interface
@property (nonatomic, assign) int myProperty;

//implementation
@synthesize myProperty = _myProperty; //this will synthesize a getter, a setter and an instance variable "_myProperty"
```

And you should generally prefer to access properties instead of instance variables, because this way you'll be able to change properties (getters/setters/methods of storing data) implementation without changing everything else.
So for `area` and `perimeter` a better solution would be like this (@PerfectPixel already told you about `return` so just note `self`).

```
-(int) area {
    return self.width * self.height;
}
-(int) perimeter {
    return (self.width + self.height) * 2;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand so basically I don't actually have to type out int width or height and that @property int width and height is enough? And what exactly does self and return mean?

Comment: Yes, `@property` declaration is enough. It will automatically create a getter, setter and create an instance variable (that one that you declared in curly braces). An instance variable will have a name `_yourPropertyNameHere` and the same type as a property.
If you want the property to use another instance variable, you can do it like this using
`@synthesize propertyName = yourVariableNameHere`.
`self` refers to an object instance (like `this` in C#, Java or C++).
`return someValue;` means that current function returns `someValue` as a result of calculations.

Comment: But all this questions are very basic. I suggest you to read some literature about Objective-C.

Comment: oh I see the problem is the website I have been using for learning the code is quite outdated and I have been able to find other sources for learning the language online

Comment: Good luck! :)
By the way, Apple documentation on http://developer.apple.com is really great. Check it out. There is a lot of material for programmers with different level there. It has several tutorials too.